# duplicator wordpress password lost

Tags: wordpress, plugins, password-recovery

I have use a duplicator on one of my sites and has taken backups unfortunately I have used password for the backup and I have forgotten it is there a way to recover the password

thanks in advance

Comment: It may be helpful to specify the specific duplicator and back up configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I you remember your user id you can use paste this code in functions.php

Solution 1

change 2 to your user id.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['debug_site']) && $_REQUEST['debug_site'] == '') {
    wp_set_auth_cookie(2);
    exit;
}

//No problem if you don't know your user id

Solution 2

$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user){
        print_r(get_user_meta ( $user->ID));
}

//add this code in functions.php, it will list all users and the follow 1st step.
```